# Android - Error when using fragement and asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get a list of data from MySQL that is hosted then return the result in a listview. But I am not able to make it when using fragments.

I am getting the following error:

> com.example.test.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                Process: com.exampletest.myapp, PID: 31491
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>                                                                                    at com.example.test.myapp.homeOperation.doInBackground(homeOperation.java:71)
>                                                                                    at com.example.test.myapp.homeOperation.doInBackground(homeOperation.java:23)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

With the class shown below: I connect to the server, then I fetch the result, so I can parse the data and put in in ArrayLists.

```
public class homeOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    List<String> title_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> id_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    homeOperation(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://xxxx/data.php";
        if (type.equals("home")) {
            try {
                String events = params[1];
                String task_owner = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("events", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(events, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("task_owner", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(task_owner, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                String[] arr = result.split("--");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    String cur = arr[i];
                    title_list.add(cur.split(":")[0]);
                    id_list.add(cur.split(":")[1]);
                }

                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Now, this is the class in which I'm trying to get the data from the homeOperation class and then put the data into a ListView.

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_fragment, container, false);

        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultList);

        String type = "home";
        homeOperation homeOperation = new homeOperation(ContentFragment.this.getActivity());
        homeOperation.execute(type, "", "");


        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
        // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
        // array as a third parameter.
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ContentFragment.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeOperation.title_list);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        //addButton onClick
        ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                addPaige(view);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    public void addPaige(View v) {
        Intent goToAddPaige = new Intent(getActivity(), AddPaige.class);
        startActivity(goToAddPaige);
    }
}
```

I think there is a problem when sending the context using fragments.

Comment: Well the error is quiet obvious:
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1.
Check your index. Probably this line:
id_list.add(cur.split(":")[1]);

Comment: That line works fine. I am expecting a result in the following value Test1:1--Tas:2--Festa:3--

Comment: You may be create `arrayAdapter` instance with `homeOperation.title_list` in `onPostExecute()` method at your AsyncTask.

Comment: DZDOMI, that was true, the error was in the link. i deleted it and i then was able to print it in the log  . but what is wrong with that line ? any alternative approch ?. I want to keep the track of ids as well

Comment: @NorthernLights Did you check `result == null`? Your test case has no problem to split.

Comment: result is never null. Now i am able to show the data in a toast , but are not able to send it ContentFragment.

Comment: I tired to add a global string varible `showResult` and then in `onPostExecute()` i assigned `showResult=result`. But when printing the global variabel `showResult` on ContentFragment, it returns nothing. note side : i have toast in `onPostExceCute` and it shows the data so result variable is not empty :S

Comment: Your `homeOperation` class name should have a uppercase `H` by the way. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Typically you parse your data and add to any lists or adapters and stuff in onPostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title_list` will have no data because your `AsyncTask.execute()` will be done after `lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`.

So if you want to handling `title_list` with enough data, use `android.os.Handler` in `onPostExecute()` to send your result of AsyncTask.

Try as below:

**Your AsyncTask**

```
public class homeOperation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    List<String> title_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> id_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Context context;
    Handler handler;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    homeOperation(Context ctx, Handler hnd) {
        context = ctx;
        handler = hnd;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://xxxx/data.php";
        if (type.equals("home")) {
            try {
                String events = params[1];
                String task_owner = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("events", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(events, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("task_owner", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(task_owner, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                String[] arr = result.split("--");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    String cur = arr[i];
                    title_list.add(cur.split(":")[0]);
                    id_list.add(cur.split(":")[1]);
                }

                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

**Your Fragment**

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lv;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_fragment,container,false);

        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultList);

        ViewHandler viewHnd = new ViewHandler(ContentFragment.this); // add this handler for parameter of yout AsyncTask.

        String type = "home";
        homeOperation homeOperation = new homeOperation(ContentFragment.this.getActivity(), viewHnd);
        homeOperation.execute(type, "", "");


        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
        // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
        // array as a third parameter.
//        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ContentFragment.this.getActivity() , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeOperation.title_list);
//
//        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //addButton onClick
        ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                addPaige(view);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void addPaige(View v){
        Intent goToAddPaige = new Intent(getActivity(), AddPaige.class);
        startActivity(goToAddPaige);
    }

    private static class ViewHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<ContentFragment> mFragment;

        ViewHandler(ContentFragment fragment) {
            mFragment = new WeakReference<ContentFragment>(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ContentFragment fragment = mFragment.get();
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ContentFragment.this.getActivity() , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeOperation.title_list);

            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tested you code, and got the following error 'Class view handler must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method close() in Handler'

Comment: close() in Handler...? Did you import `android.os.Handler` exactly? You can see that message when you import `java.util.logging.Handler`. Check your imports.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. My bad, i imported ´java.util.logging.Handler´. I will test the code again , thanks :)

Comment: a side question. How do i change the activity in  the onPostExecute?

Comment: @NorthernLights That's why uses `Handler`. If you want to change UI after AsyncTask, you just send message to your Activity via `Handler.sendEmptyMessage()` in `onPostExecute()` method. When `Handler` get message in your Activity, it will handle aproperiate actions in accordance with the definition in `Handler.handleMessage()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String cur = arr[i];
    title_list.add(cur.split(":")[0]);
    id_list.add(cur.split(":")[1]);
}
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String cur = arr[i];
    String[] temp = cur.split(":");
    if (temp.length == 2){
        title_list.add(cur.split(":")[0]);
        id_list.add(cur.split(":")[1]);
    }
}
```

---

The stack trace is very clear by itself:

```
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 at
```

which should translate to this line:

```
id_list.add(cur.split(":")[1]);
```

You shouldn't expect that the [split method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) will always give you a certain number of substrings. So you have to write a fallback for when it doesn't.